# Rails Very Large Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdbms

Rails likes to use autoincrement 32bit ints as primary keys on tables. What do people do when they get close to the limits of 32bit int # of rows in a table?

Comment: Is this an academic question, or do you have a table with over 4 billion rows?

Comment: @DanSingerman It's not an academic question. I had to work until 2am because of this issue once :) With a lot of writes and deletes it's easy to get a 4-byte id to roll over even if you only have 10s of millions of rows, and that can cause all sorts of issues.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the key to a [bigint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)?  That is an 8-byte (64-bit) integer.  It gives you up to 9 quantillion instead of 4 billion.  There isn't a native migration though, you'd have to do something like:

```
execute("ALTER TABLE massive_table CHANGE id id BIGINT")
```

**EDIT** Apparently specifying a limit on the field [as Alex suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312734/rails-very-large-table/7312875#7312875) does allow for bigints in both [PostgreSQL](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter/type_to_sql) and [mySQL](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter/type_to_sql).

Answer (score 1):

You could use 8-byte id fields. Rails doesn't provide types to create long integer or double precision columns, however it can be done using the :limit parameter:

```
create_table :my_table do |t|
  t.integer :long_int_column, :limit => 8
  t.float :double_column, :limit => 53
end
```

8 and 53 are magic numbers. This works for PostgreSQL and MySQL databases, but I haven't tried any others.

If you're altering a table, then you can write

```
change_column :my_table, :my_col, :integer, :limit => 8
```

The alternative to 8-byte id fields is to handle id rollover in some way. That would depend on the specifics of your data and application.

Comment: int(8) is not an 8-byte field.  You are simply adjusting the digit width to 8 instead of the default 11.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html  An int field is always 4 bytes.

Comment: Nope, it actually changes the type of the column created. See this post: http://moeffju.net/blog/using-bigint-columns-in-rails-migrations

Comment: Apologies, I just tested this and you are absolutely correct.  Thanks for the link.